# inventory of regex anchors

Tags: regex, anchor

1. `^` is said to match the **beginning of a line**, but it does not match right after a `"\n"`, `"\r"` or `"\r\n"`. It matches the beginning of a string, though. In what sense does it match the beginning of a line, and how is it different from `\A`?
2. `$` is said to match the **end of a line**, but it does not match right before a `"\n"`, `"\r"` or `"\r\n"`. It matches the end of a string, though. In what sense does it match the end of a line, and how is it different from `\z`?
3. `\Z`, unlike `\z`, matches right before `"\n"` if that is at the end of a string. It seems to me that `\A` and `\z` are naturally paired concept, and `\Z` is rather an odd one. Why is it that `\Z` and `\z` are defined as is, and not the other way around? And, when would you want to use `\Z`?

Can you illustrate the above using examples?
If difference among languages/standards matters, it would be helpful to list them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difference is that the `^` and `$` anchors can have modified behaviors.

With `multiline` mode on, the `^` and `$` anchors assert the beginning and end of a line.

With `multiline` mode off, the `^` and `$` anchors assert the beginning and end of the string.

---

Most regex implementations have a `multiline` mode.

With Ruby, Perl, or Javascript, it's defined with the `m` modifier.  e.g. `/pattern/m`

In .NET it's defined with `(?m)` inside the pattern itself, or from the `RegexOptions.Multiline` enumeration.

---

To answer your 3rd question...

`\A` - The match must occur at the start of the string.

`\Z` - The match must occur at the end of the string or before `\n` at the end of the string.

`\z` - The match must occur at the end of the string.

These three are constants that are not affected by any modifiers.  I agree that `\A` and `\z` seem to be an illogical pairing.  It doesn't make a great deal of sense to me either.  But in a case where you *may* have a trailing line feed that you wish to ignore then `\Z` might be preferred.

Comment: +1 The multi-line modifier also works this way for PHP and Python as well.

Comment: In Ruby, the `m` modifier denotes what most languages consider the `s` modifier (aka: DOT ALL). Quote: _"/m makes the dot match newlines. Ruby indeed uses /m, whereas Perl and many other programming languages use /s for "dot matches newlines"."_ from: http://www.regular-expressions.info/ruby.html

Comment: Also, most PCRE-like regex implementations support inline modifiers, like `(?m)`. This is not restricted to .NET.

Comment: Thanks, folks. it is becoming clear. Do you have any idea about my third question?

Comment: @sawa - There's not much to say about your 3rd question that you haven't already stated.  But I did my best above.