# What is the regex to match exactly an alphanumeric 16 character string?

Tags: regex

Here is a regex string I need to use but I only want it to match exactly 16 alphanumeric characters not the 16 within a longer string.

```
[A-Z]{6}[0-9]{2}[A-E,H,L,M,P,R-T][0-9]{2}[A-Z0-9]{5}
```

Its matches this: `PLDTLL47S04L424T` and `MRTMTT25D09F205Z` perfectly But what i dont want it to match is something like this in bold thats in middle of this long string:

> FA4127E57FE52E49BC1**FEEECC32E1246530**EE1C@BL2PRD9301MB014.024d.mgd.msft.net

Thanks in advance!

Comment: possible duplicate of [inventory of regex anchors](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5451453/inventory-of-regex-anchors)

Comment: You've already got several useful answers (and as you are a new user, please remember to mark one of them as correct, and to upvote all that you find useful) -- but I wanted to add that the commas in your regular expression are unnecessary. Also, they will match commas at the 8th character in your string, which I suspect you don't want. I think what you intend is `[A-Z]{6}[0-9]{2}[A-EHLMPR-T][0-9]{2}[A-Z0-9]{5}`.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't say which regex flavor you're using, but the issue is that you're missing start and end anchors.

Add `^` and `$` to your regex as such:

```
^[A-Z]{6}[0-9]{2}[A-E,H,L,M,P,R-T][0-9]{2}[A-Z0-9]{5}$
```

`^` means match at the start of a string, or the point after any newline in multiline mode.

`$` means the opposite:  the end of a string, or the point before the newline in multiline mode.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to my predecessors:
assuming that you want to match if and only if the line starts with something that matches your pattern, both anchor ^ and word boundary \b will do.
Ending the pattern with anchor $ and/or \b is, however, - taken into account the assumption that a line starting with something that matches, NOT correct.

See some example code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

my @tests = qw/
   AAAAAA00A00AAAAA49BC1FEEECC32E1246530EE1C@BL2PRD9301MB014.024d.mgd.msft.net
   0AAAAAA00A00AAAAA49BC1FEEECC32E1246530EE1C@BL2PRD9301MB014.024d.mgd.msft.net
/;

foreach my $test (@tests){
  if ( $test =~ /^([A-Z]{6}[0-9]{2}[A-EHLMPR-T][0-9]{2}[A-Z0-9]{5})/ ) {
    print "$1 matches\n";
  } else {
    print "NO MATCH\n";
  }
}
```

generates output:

```
marc:tmp marc$ perl test.pl
AAAAAA00A00AAAAA matches
NO MATCH
```

if you change the pattern to

```
  if ( $test =~ /^([A-Z]{6}[0-9]{2}[A-EHLMPR-T][0-9]{2}[A-Z0-9]{5}$)/ ) {
```

the result is:

```
marc:tmp marc$ perl test.pl
NO MATCH
NO MATCH
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use word boundaries `\b` for this purpose:

```
\b[A-Z]{6}[0-9]{2}[A-E,H,L,M,P,R-T][0-9]{2}[A-Z0-9]{5}\b
 ^                                                     ^
```

**Edit:** Word boundaries and not start `^` and end `$` anchors because I am assuming you just want to avoid matches as a substring and your patterns are more like your sample string but with spaces

Comment: he said that He DID NOT want it to match is something like this in bold thats in middle of this long string

Comment: @Phult This example meets those requirements and would not match the substring in bold.

Comment: @Phult what if user wants to match `FA4127E57FE52E49BC1 FEEECC32E1246530 EE1C@BL2PRD9301MB014.024d.mgd.msft.net`

Comment: Your regex is "Regex for string contains"

Comment: A word boundary is a type of anchor.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Boundry Matchers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/bounds.html) to match the beginning and endings of lines, strings, words or other things. What is available depends on your flavour of regex. The start and end of string/input matchers are pretty universal.

`^[A-Z]{6}[0-9]{2}[A-E,H,L,M,P,R-T][0-9]{2}[A-Z0-9]{5}$`

Again depending on the flavour of regex you are using you can also POSIX character classes to match alpha numerics with `\p{Alpha}` and `\p{Digit}`. This will simplfy your regex a bit.

Answer (score 0):

You should use ^ and $ to bound the regex

Answer (score -2):

You may try this regex: `^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-zA-Z])([a-zA-Z0-9]+){16}$`